# issue to parse month in simple date format

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Im getting string with value like `String val = "2012-08-01T12:00"`,and i use the following code to create calendar type from it ,the problem is when i print the data i get for month 07 instead 08 ,how can i solve it to get the exactly month?

> 1-7-2012-12-0-0

```
    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
                    Date date = null;               
                    date = parserSDF.parse(Val);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-"
                        + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                        + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is here:

```
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

January = 0 (**not** 1), February = 1 (**not 2**), etc

Comment: @JohnJerrby don't do anything in cal.setTime(), month is 0 based by convention, you rather do ... + (cal.get(calendar.MONTH) + 1) + ... in your System.out.println()

Comment: there is no way to handle it by the set method since I need to update it to some API and this API doesnt add one to the month ,meantime there is a way to handle it somehow by the set method?

Comment: if the API you're using takes a Calendar object and it uses cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) as 1 based, then the API has a bug, there is not much you can do about it, unless you have the code of such API

Comment: If you have an API that uses `String` concatenation and access to the underlying `Calendar` properties to stringify a `Calendar` then the writer of the API should be found, concatenated and then...

Answer (score 1):

[`month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) is 0 based, so what you get is alright.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one.

`Calendar` [returns the month in the range 0-11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), so adding `1` will translate it into the 1-12 range we're all familiar with.

Quoting javadocs linked above:

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is
>   JANUARY which is 0

Comment: If i want to handle it in the set method and not in the syso there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Months are zero indexed in the Calendar. If you want to get a one indexed Month you need to use *another* `SimpleDateFormat` with a format of `MM`.

So, instead of your strange `String` concatenation you would use

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
System.out.println(formatter.format(cal));
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Hi Boris this is not a strange string I need it since this is Odata datetime format...i cannot change it.

Comment: `String` concatenation **is not how a `Calendar` is turned into a `String`**. A `Calendar` has an _internal_ representation of its data and that **shouldn't concern you**. You  should use the `SimpleDateFormat` to convert `Calendar` to/from `String`s.